# Unable to find value using variable as field name in find() method within Mongo Shell

Tags: mongo-shell

I've executed the following command in mongo shell:

```
db.perscoll.insert({CT:{English:{genre:[{name:varGenre}]}}})
```

Now, i want to find whether genre for 'English' exists in the collection or not using find(), which will return either 0(false) or 1(true).

```
db.perscoll.find({'CT.English.genre.name':varGenre}).count();
```

The above command returns me 1(true), but when i try to execute the same command using variable as mentioned below, it returns 0 .

```
var eType = 'CT';
var lang = 'English';
var varGenre = 'Action';
var gnrNameChk = {}; 
gnrNameChk[eType+'.'+lang+'.genre.name'] = ''; 
print(gnrNameChk);
db.perscoll.find({gnrNameChk:varGenre}).count();
```

What can be the problem? how to tackle this? I'm not getting any way to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
      var eType = 'CT';
      var lang = 'English';
      var varGenre = 'Action';
     var gnrNameChk = {}; 
      gnrNameChk[eType+'.'+lang+'.genre.name'] = varGenere; 
      print(gnrNameChk);
     db.perscoll.find(gnrNameChk).count();

Hope that helps you!!!